# BODY tag disappear when using Jquery.Load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to make a pop-up like window using jquery and its modal box. First I load the content from a html file:

```
$("#test").load("test.htm");
```

Then I load the popup:

```
$("#test").dialog("open");
```

This works like it should, the content of test.html is injectet into the modal pop-up. There is only one think that is wrong, and that is the BODY tags are gone from the source of the pop-up. I need the BODY tag to be there because I do some formatting based on the BODY tag.

Does anyone know why jQuery.Load() removes the BODY tag? And are there any workarounds?

Comment: " I do some formatting based on the BODY tag ".. Why not use a wrapper div and format that instead? Saves you the headache of trying to insert a <body> tag into an existing <body> element, which is definately not valid HTML.

Comment: I would like to do that, but I get the files from an external XML-source and I do not have control of the markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading the HTML into an existing document that already has a body tag.  A document can only have one so it automatically filters anything and extracts only the HTML inside the body tag when using load.  You should wrap your HTML in a div with a specific class and do your formatting based on that class.

From the [load](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load#urldatacallback) docs (emphasis mine):

> In jQuery 1.2 you can now specify a
>   jQuery selector in the URL. Doing so
>   will filter the incoming HTML
>   document, only injecting the elements
>   that match the selector. The syntax
>   looks something like "url #some >
>   selector". **Default selector "body>*"
>   always applies.** If the URL contains a
>   space it should be escape()d. See the
>   examples for more information.

Answer (score 1):

A page can only have one body tag. If you already have one on the page, the second will be ignored.

In your case, it sounds like the browser is ignoring the duplicate body (nothing specific to jquery). Rather than use the body for styling, use a containing `<div>` with an id or class which will be retained.

Answer (score 1):

It probably removes the `body` tag because it's not allowed! Each document can only have one body. Rather than force everyone to redo all their HTML pages, jQuery probably just grabs the contents of the `body` to use when you call `load()`.

Have you thought about perhaps wrapping everything in a containing element? eg: `<div class="body">` You can then apply the exact same styles to that element.

```
/* change this: */
body { color: #f0f; etc }

/* to this: */
body, div.body { color: #f0f; }
```

Comment: +1, perfect example, and requires the least work of all possible solutions.

Comment: This is a good answer. Perhaps it would be improved by using the dialog's class (from memory, its ui-dialog), although that depends on whether he's using dialogs for any other reason. I get the feeling he isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You might dynamically create the body tag using document.write of js as an alternative.

Comment: This is going to be dynamic later, meaning I'm going to fetch the HTML code from an XML-file and load it into the DIV using an ASP.NET handler (ashx-file).

So I cant really add the body tag using javascript since I dont know on which lines to add it since the document im going to load might change.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and solved it more or less as the following: 
instead of using load(), you can use get(), and do some smart string replacement:

```
var content = get("test.htm")
               .replace("<body>", "<body><div class='body'>")
               .replace("</body>", "</body>");
$("#test").replace($(content).filter(".body"));
```